# PHP XMLReader - Reading not properly formated XML files

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

This question is related to another post I've posted here (for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509947/import-xml-in-php-to-add-to-mysql-db/48520038#48520038))

I'm FTP downloading log files from an open data rail project in the UK, and the log files are about 3Mb each and presented this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" ts="2018-02-05T21:33:59.8558288Z" version="12.0"><uR updateOrigin="Darwin"><deactivated rid="201802058015464"/></uR></Pport>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-02-05T21:33:59.8558288Z" version="12.0"><uR updateOrigin="Darwin"><TS rid="201802058709918" ssd="2018-02-05" uid="W09918"><ns3:Location tpl="DARTFD" wta="07:36"><ns3:arr delayed="true" et="21:34" src="Darwin"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">2</ns3:plat></ns3:Location></TS></uR></Pport>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-02-05T21:33:59.8558288Z" version="12.0"><uR updateOrigin="Darwin"><TS rid="201802058771469" ssd="2018-02-05" uid="W71469"><ns3:Location tpl="WLWYCSD" wtd="13:16"><ns3:dep delayed="true" et="21:34" src="Darwin"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="WLWYNGC" wtp="13:18"><ns3:pass delayed="true" et="21:36" src="Darwin"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">3</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="HATFILD" wtp="13:21:30"><ns3:pass delayed="true" et="21:39" src="Darwin"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsrc="A" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="POTRSBR" wtp="13:26"><ns3:pass delayed="true" et="21:44" src="Darwin"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="ALEXNDP" wtp="13:36:30"><ns3:pass delayed="true" et="21:51" src="Darwin"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">2</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="HRGYURV" wta="13:43" wtd="13:48"><ns3:arr delayed="true" et="21:57" src="Darwin"/><ns3:dep delayed="true" et="21:58" src="Darwin"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="HRNSYMD" wta="13:50"><ns3:arr delayed="true" et="22:00" src="Darwin"/></ns3:Location></TS></uR></Pport>
```

To further add, sometimes the last entry, is a broken entry, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2018-02-05T21:34:52.2569006Z" version="12.0"><uR updateOrigin="Trust"><TS rid="201802056757064" ssd="2018-02-05" uid="C57064"><ns3:Location pta="21:34" ptd="21:34" tpl="DEVNPRT" wta="21:34" wtd="21:34:30"><ns3:arr at
```

I have used the advice given here and tried to implement a PHP solution using XMLReader, however the way the XML log file is setup, XMLReader throughs errors.

This is the base code I'm using:

```
$xmlReader->open($filename);

// While there is something to read continue reading
    while ($xmlReader->read()) { 

    // check to ensure nodeType is an Element not attribute or #Text  
        if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

            if ($xmlReader->hasAttributes) {
//Do something here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

One solution I thought since each of the entries in the log file are single lines, I thought I could open the file, and read and load into the XMLReader, but I have not being able to do it, like this:

```
if ($filename = fopen("./pPortData.log", "r")) {
       while (!feof($filename)) {
            $xmlstr = fgets($filename);
            # do same stuff with the $line
            $address = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            echo $address->getName(), PHP_EOL;
            foreach($address as $name => $part) {
                echo "$name: $part" . "/n/r", PHP_EOL;
            }
        }    
        fclose($xmlstr);
    }
```

But no joy. So ...

1) Do you know a way of achieving this pls?

2) Or do you know how to load line by line from a file into XMLReader?

3) How do I fix the XML file?

Thank you

Lucio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your last effort, loading each line at a time and then processing them with SimpleXML should be OK.

I've made a few changes, I've added some error trapping which picks up the last record potentially being incomplete and just displays a message.  The other part is just about how you process the XML data, so at the moment I just output the data from the loaded XML.

```
if ($file = fopen("./pPortData.log", "r")) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $xmlstr = fgets($file);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        try {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
            echo $xml->getName(), PHP_EOL;
            foreach($xml->children() as $part) {
                echo $part->asXML() . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )  {
            echo "Last part unreadable.".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great - Clap Clap :)